# Bootstrap 3 datepicker: Change date display format; Prevent date selections prior to Todays date

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, calendar

I am using the Bootstrap datepicker for the first time on a hotel site.  I have gotten it installed and it does display the calendar as it should.

However, the date, once picked, is displayed in this format: dd.mm.yyyy (ie: 28.10.2020).  **I would like for it to display like this dd MMM, yyyy (ie: 28 Oct, 2020)**.  I tried using the class datepicker, and this code (as can be seen below) - but it didn't work: `$('.datepicker').datepicker({format: 'dd MMM, yyyy', todayHighlight: true});`

In addition, **I would like the calendar to not allow you to pick any date before today's date.**  (So all past dates are greyed out and can't be selected.)

You can see calendar on the test page here: [www.citycentrebudgethotel.com.au/stage/default.asp](https://www.citycentrebudgethotel.com.au/stage/default.asp)

Here are the header scripts:

```
<!-- JAVASCRIPT 1/2 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- CSS Global Compulsory -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">

<!-- CSS Implementing Plugins -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/line-icons/line-icons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/layer-slider/layerslider/css/layerslider.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/sky-forms-pro/skyforms/css/sky-forms.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/sky-forms-pro/skyforms/custom/custom-sky-forms.css">
<!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/sky-forms-pro/skyforms/css/sky-forms-ie8.css"><![endif]-->

<!-- CSS Customization -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/custom.css">
```

Here are the footer scripts:

```
<!-- JS Global Compulsory -->
<!-- JAVASCRIPT 2/2 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

<!-- JS Implementing Plugins -->           
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/back-to-top.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/layer-slider/layerslider/js/greensock.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/layer-slider/layerslider/js/layerslider.transitions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/layer-slider/layerslider/js/layerslider.kreaturamedia.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/sky-forms-pro/skyforms/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 

<!-- JS Customization -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/custom.js"></script> 

<!-- JS Page Level -->           
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/layer-slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/datepicker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        App.init();
        App.initFancybox();
        LayerSlider.initLayerSlider();
        Datepicker.initDatepicker();
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',
            helpers : {
                media : {}
            }
        });
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            format: 'dd MMM, yyyy',
            todayHighlight: true
        });         
    }); 
</script>
```

Here is the code to display the calendar fields:

```
    <form action="#" id="sky-form" class="sky-form">
        <div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
            <section class="col-md-6">
                <label class="input">
                    <i class="icon-append fa fa-calendar"></i>
                    <input type="text" name="start" id="start" placeholder="Check In Date" class="datepicker">
                </label>
            </section>
            <section class="col-md-6">
                <label class="input">
                    <i class="icon-append fa fa-calendar"></i>
                    <input type="text" name="finish" id="finish" placeholder="Check out Date" class="datepicker">
                </label>
            </section>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to format the date display, and to restrict past dates.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Disable past dates:

Bootstrap Datepicker offers the option for `startDate`:

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate

creating a new Date object without giving it any options will default to today:

```
var d = new Date():
```

try using this for the `startDate` option:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({startDate: new Date()});
```

### toDisplay formatting

Quotes matter, try double quotes around your format:

`$('.datepicker').datepicker({format: "dd MMM, yyyy", todayHighlight: true});`

If this fails, I sometimes find I need to set this value via `toDisplay`:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  format: {
    // We're sending an object, not a string
    toDisplay: function (date, format, language) {
      // this gets messy, sorry
      var d = new Date(date);
      var year = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { year: 'numeric' }).format(d);
      var month = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { month: 'short' }).format(d);
      var day = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { day: '2-digit' }).format(d);
      return day + " " + month + ", " + year;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you @chiperific for your quick reply.  For Past dates, I see it is startDate option, but I can't figure out how to set it to today's date (not a specific date, but whatever the TODAY date is.)  Can you provide an example?  For Format dates, I tried both of your suggestions.  Neither worked.  I think maybe I am not picking up this code for some reason?  Am I pulling in the class in the wrong place?  Can you see anything that I may have coded wrong to not be accessing this function? Would some other plugin code be overriding this?

Comment: I just noticed that the format option has a Default: “mm/dd/yyyy”, but my date is displaying as dd.mm.yyyy (with periods instead of slashes, and also using the Australian date format, which is good for me, but not the default format).  So if I am not picking up this function, then I should be seeing the default format, which I am not doing either.  So now I really do think that there is maybe another script somewhere that is setting it differently?  Is there anyway to figure that out?

Comment: On the Australian date format, it might be that something is localizing your format: `new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-AU');`, either the browser or Javascript.

Comment: I added some sample code for `startDate` to get you headed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I have found out the problem.  My version of bootstrap/datepicker is different from the one that the documentation refers to and doesn't use the same variable names.  This is why the great suggestion by Chiperific didn't work for me.

I have gone ahead and marked his answer as correct, as it would have provided the correct solution, if I had a normal setup.

For anyone else running into this kind of problem, I will post here the datepicker.js that my site is using.  This script has been adjusted to display the dates in the format I wanted, and to also not allow past dates to be selected:

```
var Datepicker = function () {

  return {
    
    //Datepickers
    initDatepicker: function () {
        // Regular datepicker
        $('#date').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd MM, yy',
            prevText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
            nextText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'
        });
        
        // Date range
        $('#start').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd MM, yy',
            prevText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
            nextText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>',
            minDate: 'TODAY()',
            onSelect: function( selectedDate )
            {
                $('#finish').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate);
            }
        });
        $('#finish').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd MM, yy',
            prevText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
            nextText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>',
            onSelect: function( selectedDate )
            {
                $('#start').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', selectedDate);
            }
        });
        
        // Inline datepicker
        $('#inline').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd MM, yy',
            prevText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
            nextText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'
        });
        
        // Inline date range
        $('#inline-start').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd MM, yy',
            prevText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
            nextText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>',
            onSelect: function( selectedDate )
            {
                $('#inline-finish').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate);
            }
        });
        $('#inline-finish').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd MM, yy',
            prevText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
            nextText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>',
            onSelect: function( selectedDate )
            {
                $('#inline-start').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', selectedDate);
            }
        });
    }

  };
}();
```